# How do I shorten the pull to refresh distance (threshold) in React Native Refresh Control

Tags: reactjs, scrollview, react-native, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to implement pull to refresh using Refresh Control in ScrollView. I need to modify the pulling distance/threshold of refresh control. I have checked for the related props to achieve it, but I can't any props related to this.

```
<ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.subContainer}
          bounces={true}
          horizontal={false}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={false}
              tintColor={'transparent'}
              onRefresh={() => {
                onSwipeDown();
              }}
            />
          }
        >
          {props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by onScroll event listener.

```
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={styles.subContainer}
    bounces={true}
    horizontal={false}
    onScroll={onSwipeDown}
  >
   {props.children}
  </ScrollView>
```

onSwipeDown method

```
 const onSwipeDown = event => {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
    if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < 0) { // you can replace zero with needed threshold
      onRefresh(); //your refresh function
    }
  };
```